# to show thumbnail along with recent posts on blog page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id); ?>
```

Above is the code that i am using on page but nothing is showing on page,want to show thumbnail of recent post along with the content on blog page

Comment: Does the post have a thumbnail? Get sure that $post_id contains the the right ID (usually $post->ID)

Comment: yes it have on blog i am showing recent 5 posts ,content is showing but i want thumbnail also for content i using a plugin its code is[rpfc_recent_posts_from_category excerpt="true" meta="true" ]

Comment: Tschan any solution pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the WP_Query method ? If not then use

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'=> your_desired_number_of_post,
);

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<li>';
        $the_query->the_post();
         the_post_thumbnail();
         the_content();
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
else {
    echo 'no posts found';
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: not working i am placing this on blog-template.php ,i am doing right

Comment: have you included `<?php` at the very `beginning` and `?>` at the `end`. Also tell me what do you see on the screen.

Comment: i have updated the code. add the $args array before the query. That should be good.

Comment: thnku Muhamad Muzahir Khodabucus

Comment: it is showing picture now but now it is showing the full content of post how to set limit for that ,i want to show only post on page and little about that recent post

Comment: i have set no of post now how can i set size of thumbnail image

Comment: you can set an image size in wordpress like so: add_image_size( 'image_name', 220, 220, array( 'center', 'center' ) ) in your functions.php file; you can use any image name. instead of 220 use any number you want. and array(center, center) means that the image will be cropped from the center horizontally and vertically. then use this code :    $the_query->the_post();
         the_post_thumbnail('image_name');  you can then use the_excerpt() instead of the_content and that will show a maximum of 55 words i think. A little vote will do just good for me !

Comment: thnku so much it worked ,how can i vote for u i will dfntly do that

Comment: you can click on the up arrow where the answer begins and you can also accept this answer as an right answer by clicking the tick below the up and   down arrow where the answer (not this comment) begins. Additionally go to this page to know more http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work